# RadioButtonList null values

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

have a radiobutton list which I am filling with Strings and would like to know how to get in a given time the value of the selected element and throw it into a String for example. but with the command SelectedValue and SelectedItem only have null values​​.

This radio button list is filled several times during the execution of the same page.

```
//Where do you fill the RadioButtonList
public void MostraImagensCarrefadas()
{
    List<String> files = new manFile().getListFilesForDirectory(this, MAE.DIRETORIO_TEMP_IMG);

    rbImagemPrincipal.Items.Clear();

    if (files != null)
    {
        foreach (String item in files)
        {
            rbImagemPrincipal.Items.Add(new ListItem(item));
        }
    }
}


//As it is in aspx
<div>
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbImagemPrincipal" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" AutoPostBack="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbImagemPrincipal_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:RadioButtonList>
```

```
 //where only encounter null values ​​when trying to get the selected item (clicked)
 //Nothing I do is the value obtained direferente null.
if (rbImagemPrincipal.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    if (rbImagemPrincipal.SelectedItem.ToString() == str)
                    {
                        imagem.imagemPrincipal = "SIM";

                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're populating the RadioButtonList on the page load -
 If so - make sure you surround your population of the RadioButtonList with an
 If/Then/Postback block:
 if not Page.IsPostBack then
 ' populate your RBL
 end if

eg:

```
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            loadradiobuttonlist();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is the page let you know the value, not the application is getting it.

So, you need a ScriptManager and Timer, both are Ajax extensions. Add them to the page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer1.Interval = 2000; // set your interval
}
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int result =  RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex;
}
```

`result` is your radiobuttonlist selection index. Use it to select item from list.